# Avoid <> with default template class/struct in C++

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

Suppose

```
template<class T>
struct S{
    T x;
    a(T xx){x=xx;}
};
```

and that we wish to ease the most common use by more than just a default specialization wishing to omit the empty angle brackets. One could reach for typedef

```
typedef S<int> defaut_S;
default_S(1);
```

but here the consistency is broken in a way, as `default_S` has a different name than `S`, and can cause confusion with the user. Not to mention that it won't work for member functions.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking. Obviously `default_S` has a different name to `S` so it's not clear why you think that fact causes confusion; also there is no problem with member functions.

Comment: C++17 lets you deduce class template parameters from constructors.

Comment: I thought, the above approach could lead to confusion, because we have the same class, that is conceptually the same in both names, this may cause confusion. Perhaps someone thinking they come from a different class. Or is this preferred, as you want them to be treated as separate classes? No, there is no problem with member functions, I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the instantiator function pattern.

```
template <class T>
struct S
{
  T x;
  void a(T xx) { x = xx; }
};

template <class T=int>
S<T> make_s() { return S<T>(); }

int main()
{
  auto s = make_s();
  auto t = make_s<double>();
}
```